# onload='setInterval("function()",1000)' doesn't work

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, html

I have an xml file and i want to load its contents into a specific html div every one second, here's the javascript part that parses the xml file:

```javascript
function getEntries() {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = handleReq;
    req.open("GET", "entries.xml", true);
    req.send(null);

}
function handleReq() {
    if (req.readyState == 4)
        document = req.responseXML;
    var states = document.getElementsByTagName("entry");
    for (i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
        currentState = states[i];
        document.getElementById("LogArea").innerHTML = "<table><tr><td><b>Name:</b></td><td>"
                + currentState.getAttribute("umessage");
        +"</td></tr><tr><td><b>Message:</b></td><td>"
                + currentState.getAttribute("uname");
        +"</td></tr></table>";
    }
}
```

and here's the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<entries>
<entry umessage="aaaaaaaa" uname="aaaaaaa" />
<entry umessage="Hello everybody" uname="John" />
<entry umessage="Hello everybody" uname="Smith" />
<entry umessage="Hello everybody" uname="Knuth" />
</entries>
```

and that's the html part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body bgcolor="yellow" onload='setInterval("getEntries()",1000)'>
<div id="LogArea" align="left">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem is that nothing is loaded in the specified div and no errors exists inside firebug

Comment: Is the JavaScript loaded the <body> tag?

Comment: Can you expand on "doesn't work"? What _is_ happening that you don't expect? What is not happening that you are? Exceptions? Errors?

Comment: The code works for me here, what browser, have you tried outputing any data with a console.log? JQuery would make this a little easier in my opinnion but apart from the function call should be "getEntries" and not "getEntries()" then it should all be ok, post the full code in your single file

Comment: This isn't related to your actual problem, but your `getEntries` function looks a bit odd. You check whether `XMLHttpRequest` is defined, and set up `rec` if it is, but then you carry on and use `rec` regardless, which means the initial check is a bit pointless because it'll still break if `XMLHttpRequest` isn't defined anyway. In any case, `XMLHttpRequest` will always be defined, unless you need to support IE7 or earlier. If you need to support IE7, then you need to adjust you ajax code to work with it. If not, you can just drop the `if()` check entirely, as it's not helping you in any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to overwrite `document` in `function handleReq()` so that it refers to the XML instead of the HTML. Whether this succeeds or fails, it's still not going to work.

First, you try to set `document` to be the XML you loaded asynchronously. As mentioned in the comments, this probably fails (in my tests, neither Chrome nor IE 9 allowed me to overwrite `document` in this manner).

```
document = req.responseXML;
var states = document.getElementsByTagName("entry");
```

If it fails, then `states` is looking for `<entry>` tags in your HTML page (not what you intended). If it succeeds, then you have a problem two lines later because you expect `document` to magically be the HTML page again instead of the XML:

```
document.getElementById("LogArea").innerHTML = ...
```

- Don't use variable names that are properties of `window` -- call your XML response something else, like `var xmldoc = ...`.
- Don't use global variables. You should be using `var whatever = ...` instead of `whatever = ...` to define function variables.
- As other have mentioned, `setTimeout(String, ...)` is bad practice and deprecated. Functions are full-fledged objects in JavaScript, so just pass the function itself (no quotes, not parentheses).
- The entire body of `function handleReq()` should be inside of the `if (req.readyState == 4)` block (not just the first line). You don't want to do anything if the request hasn't finished yet.

Comment: +1 I don't think you can overwrite the document so when `document.getElementsByTagName("entry");` is actually looking for `entry` tags in the page not the xml.

Comment: @Musa Thanks, that appears to be correct. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
setInterval(getEntries,1000)
```

Instead of passing in a string that would be `eval`ed, pass in the function name directly.

An additional problem is in your `handleReq` method, as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15590997/1583):

```
document = req.responseXML;
```

That *replaces* the document, meaning that your next few lines are referring to something that is no longer there.

Answer (score 2):

Passing a string as the first paramater is bad / depreciated. Instead use either:

```
setInterval(getEntries, 1000);
```

or if you need to pass paramaters:

```
setInterval(function(){ getEntries('foo') }, 1000);
```

Although that probably will not solve your problem, it's important to keep in mind.